# Getting too many matches for regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a regex tester in JS. However, it appears that for some regexes, I get multiple matches.

For example, if for the content `hello, world`, the regex `hello.*` is given, the it is reported to match `hello, world`. However, if the regex is now set to `(hello|goodbye).*` then the reported matches are `hello, world` and `hello`, whereas it should be `hello, world` only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Regex tester</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function resetform() {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
            }

            function escapetags(str) {
                return (str.replace('&','&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;'));
            }

            function check() {
                if (!document.form1.re.value) {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<p style="color:red"><b>Error: No regular expression specified</b></p>';
                    return;
                }
                if (!document.form1.str.value) {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<p style="color:red"><b>Error: No content specified</b></p>';
                    return;
                }
                var pattern,
                modifiers = "";
                if (document.form1.nocase.checked) {
                    modifiers = "i";
                }
                if (document.form1.global.checked) {
                    modifiers = modifiers + "g";
                }
                try {
                    if (modifiers) {
                        pattern = new RegExp(document.form1.re.value, modifiers);
                    } else {
                        pattern = new RegExp(document.form1.re.value);
                    }
                } catch (excpt) {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<p style="color:red"><b>Error: Invalid regular expression</b></p>';
                    return;
                }
                var matches = pattern.exec(document.form1.str.value);
                if (matches == null) {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<p><b>Regular expression did not match with content<b></p>';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '<p><b>Regular expression matched with content</b></p><p>Matches:</p>';
                    for (var index = 0; index < matches.length; index++) {
                        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += escapetags(matches[index]) + '<br>';
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <h1>Regex tester</h1>
        <form name="form1">
            <p>Regex:</p>
            <input type="text" name="re" size="65"><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="nocase">Case insensitive
            <input type="checkbox" name="global">Global
            <p>Content:</p>
            <textarea name="str" rows="8" cols="65"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="check();">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset();resetform();">
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me find the problem in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, your `escapeTags()` is wrong; it needs to escape `&`.

Comment: @SLaks, edited to correct `escapeTags()`, thanks.

Comment: The brackets define a capturing group. You are matching the entire string and capturing the group in the brackets.

Comment: @user2064000: Now it's even worse.  (try it)

Comment: @SLaks, where's the problem?

Comment: @user2064000: `>` will become `&amp;gt;`

Comment: Edited (again) to correct `escapetags()`, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*(hello|goodbye).* then the reported matches are hello, world and hello*"

No, the second "match" is just the result of your capturing group (what's between the parenthesis). Ignore it, or make the group non-capturing: `(?:hello|goodbye)`

Answer (score 1):

The `.exec()` method of the JavaScript regex will return the entire matched string as the first element and then any captured groups as subsequent elements. When you use the regex:

```
(hello|goodbye).*
```

The brackets define a capture group, so your returned array will be

```
[0] = hello, world
[1] = hello
```

As Loamhoof suggest below, you can add `?:` to make a group non-capturing if that is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
var a = new RegExp("hello, world"); //or your string
var b = "hello, world";
if(a.test(b)){
   //do your stuff
}
else{
   //do your stuff
}
```

it will only match for the given pattern.